# Javascript: onmouseover and onmouseout image opacity change

Tags: javascript, arrays, onmouseover, getelementsbytagname, onmouseout

I am having issues figuring out how to get this working with pure Javascript. I know that by using `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` I will need to loop through each instance of an image.

I am having no luck with everything I have tried. So far, I am just trying to test with the first image only.

```
var change = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        console.log(change);
        change[0].onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};

        change[0].onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
        function mouseOver() {
            change[0].style.opacity = '0.6';
        }

        function mouseOut() {
            change[0].style.opacity = '1';
        }
```

Comment: `for (const img of ...) { img.onmouseover = () => img.style.opacity = '0.6';` etc

Comment: You also need to add the `mouseout` listener

Comment: Sounds like you don't have any images in the DOM when your code runs.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am assuming this would be equivalent. 
`for(const img of document.getElementsByTagName('img')) {img.onmouseover = () => img.style.opacity = '0.6';}` My problem with this, is it does not output anything. I have even added to my original script for a testing the constant, with `const nodeItems = Array.from(change);` then trying to `console.log(nodeItems` returns no values.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was editing the comment to give it more detail. I will check into that. Thanks.